# Nested Ressources in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resources, routes, nested

It's actually supposed to be very trivial, but I'm experiencing strange issues.

I'm developing a Game Database, where Users can chart Game Entries and also write reviews to those reviews. Of course a Reviews URL (the show view) must be dependent of the game's id, like localhost:3000/games/1/reviews/2

So these are my routes

```
resources :games do
  resources :reviews
end
```

And I want to open the show-view of a review with

```
<%= link_to "zum Review", game_review_path(@game, @review) %>
```

this is all basic tutorial stuff.

But I only recieve a Routing error. Trying instead this approach

```
url_for([@game, @review])
```

At least won't result in a routing error, but Not the reviews show-view is opened, but the game's show view, which is where this link is actually placed!

My models associations are set corretly and my controllers actions are all basic tutorial stuff. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you restarted the server?

Answer (score 0):

In your erb file try passing the local variable in the left argument and the name of the nested model in the field to the right. If you use 2 local variables you will get a routing error. @game is the local variable and review is nested under games so the below code should fix your issue.

Try:

```
<%= link_to "zum Review", game_review_path(@game, review) %>
```

Comment: It would be more useful to @SirJay if you added some context to this answer, since it's a bit of a guess at the problem. If it's correct then OP could use more of an explanation to avoid the same mistake again.

Comment: it worked! Now the link directs me right to the correct reivew show...thanks so much! but I have two ask two more questions. why does it work that way? I mean my tutorial book and the guide on rubyrails.org tells you to use two local variables...your working solution is complete off those tutorials..also (and much more important) my helper path "game_review_path" only works because I use in my routes get "games/:game_id/reviews/:id" => "reviews#show", as: "review". But shouldn't this route be included in my nested resource already? without this my review_Path method is undefined. but why?